# Update Vungle-ads 7.0.0 in iOS

Tags: swift, sdk, google-mobile-ads, vungle-ads

I am updating Vungle SDK to 7.0.0. Not able to find proper documentation for the conversion of old codes to new. Please help.

1. import VungleAdapter // This is no longer exist. Is VungleAdsSDK the replacement?
2. How to register extras in new version? What is the replacement code for below?

```
    let request = GADRequest()
    let extras = VungleAdNetworkExtras()
    let placements = ["xxx"]
    extras.allPlacements = placements
    request.register(extras)
```

Please provide the link if there is some documentation available on this. Thanks

I have updated 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', to '10.4.0' and GoogleMobileAdsMediationVungle to 7.0.0
Managed to convert the code for updating VungleSDK consent.
I have gone through this documentation as well.
[https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002925791](https://stackoverflow.com)
But couldn't find anything about registering the extras.